# How is aliases working in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I got a question from a colleague of mine, that might be a silly question, but I wasn't able to provide an answer on the spot.

I have the following query

```
SELECT sc.custid, contactname, orderid, empid
FROM Sales.Customers sc
INNER JOIN Sales.Orders so ON sc.custid = so.custid;
```

The `custid` it's obvious that it can be found on both tables. The `contactname` belongs to `Sales.Customers` table and the `orderid` and `empid` to `Sales.Orders`. So far so good.

Taking out the alias from `custid` at the beginning of the `SELECT` statement, will raise an error saying the name is ambiguous, which is correct because it is present in both tables. But, using the alias to define which `custid` to retrieve and from what tables, after that I was not forced to use aliases for other three columns and the query completed successfully. Why?

I'm a beginner in SQL so treat the question as it comes. Thanks

Comment: If the other three column names aren't ambiguous, then you don't need to disambiguate them.

Comment: Imagine if you had two friends named Bob. One is named Bob Smith and the other is Bob Foo. If you had to explain a story to a mutual friend of both Bob's by saying "one time Bob and I..." they would ask which Bob? But if you said "one time Bob Smith and I..." they would know immediately who you're talking about. Alias is about clarifying associations in table(s) with the same column names.

Comment: @cdrrrrr, I suggest you make a habit of qualifying column names with the table name or alias in multi-table queries. That makes the query easier to understand and maintain for those who are not familiar with the underlying schema.

Comment: And also a bit safer as the query won’t be broken by adding an additional column to one of the tables that makes a previously unambiguous reference ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you didn't need to explicitly specify the alias name in other columns is because *other columns are unique across all the tables specified in your query and could be identified without the table name*. Whenever it is ambiguous, then you must specify from which table the column should be used, like in the case of your `custId` column. In your case:

```
sc.custId is same as Sales.Customer.custId
```

As you might have noticed, one advantage with using `alias` is that it requires much less typing.